# Trouble making a div with a background-image with fixed height and width responsive

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

As you can see, I'm trying to make `container` which a `background-image` responsive when I minimize my browser's window.

I've tried playing with `max-width` ,`percentages`, `background-size:cover`  and a few other tricks but they didn't work or they made my container disappear.

Pug

```
section
  div(class='container')
```

SASS

```
section
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: gray
  .container
    position: absolute
    background: url('https://www.triplejtours.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lake-Kununurra-reflections-Dylan-Lodge.jpg')
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center
    background-size: cover
    height: 807px
    width: 948px
    left: 50%
    top: 50%
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Padvpg)

Comment: fixed height/width and responsive? can you elaborate how exactly?

Comment: The image which I'm using for has a height of 807 px and a width of 948 px. So the container should also have that measurements. I know my premise is bad and vague. Is  there any way so I can make this container responsive ?

Comment: and how you want the responsive to behave?

Comment: when I minimize my browser window I want it to shrink alongside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex; /*use flex to easily center*/
  background: gray;
}

.container>div {
  background: url('https://www.triplejtours.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lake-Kununurra-reflections-Dylan-Lodge.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; /*keep it center within the centred div*/
  background-size: contain; /*use contain to make the image shrink visually*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto; /*center the div*/
  max-width: 948px; /*Image width*/
  max-height: 807px; /*Image height*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```