# Positioning image in css

Tags: html, css

How do I position my image tag so it will always be 100% of divs height, proportional that would be cut out b the div.
For example, if my image is 260x180, and my div is 50x90. i want the image to shrink to size of 130x 90, and positioned in the center of the div.

```
img{
   max-width: 100%;  
   height: 208px; 
   width: 100%; 
   display: block;
   object-fit: auto 100%;
}
```

I tried with object-fit and similar, but it didn`t work. And i cant put it as a background image either.

Comment: Why can't you put as a background-image?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050709/trouble-making-a-div-with-a-background-image-with-fixed-height-and-width-respons/51050976#51050976

Comment: Because the images come from the database

Comment: Your div is 50*90 and you want to shrink image to 130*90 ? How is this possible when div is smaller than image. either it will shrink the image to 50px width or it will hide extra area of image or it will stretch the image.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that question was how to center it as a background image, and i specifically said that i cannot do that

Comment: @vaishalikapadia so basically my div is 90px tall, i want image to be the height of 90px and without deformation, so that would be 90 px of height and 130px(twice ass small) in width. since div is 50px wide, i want to hide 80px from the image, 40 from both sides

Comment: @Liondj ok now I got it

Comment: and that's why it's called a *possible* duplcate ;) and I didn't close as a duplicate ... *you* cannot use background image but someone else who find your question can use it and this link may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this.

```css
div {
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 90px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  //overflow: hidden; /* toggle this to hide sides */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1/* to show sizing & centering */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/260/180" alt="">
</div>

<h2> Original Image </h2>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/260/180" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your parant `div`,

`.div {overflow:hidden; text-align:center;}`

and remove height from img.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image{
  max-width: 100%;  
   height: 100%; 
   width: 50%; 
  
}
.content{
  text-align: center;
 overflow:hidden;
  height: 200px;  /*Height of the div*/
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="" class="image">

</div>
```